# How to plot a summation in Python 3

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a function and use pyplot to plot it. This is the function:

[image]

```
-2.048 <= xi <= 2.048 and n = 2
```

This is my code:

```py
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot
from numpy import arange

x = arange(-2.048, 2.048)
x2 = x + 1
y = (100 * ((x2 - (x ** 2)) ** 2)) + ((x - 1) ** 2)
plot(x, y)
```

I want the plotting of the function in -2.048 and 2.048

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: You want the function between -2.048 and 2.048, or -2048 and 2048?

Comment: can you be more specific about what you want?